# Why is header() of php not working?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-modal

I am using AJAX to register users to a service. 
Following is the markup of submit button.

```
<input type="button" id="register" name="register" class="btn btn-success" onclick="registration();" value="Register"/>
```

and Following is registration() function and other javascript-

```
    function registration()
    {
        var name = document.getElementById("regname").value;                
        var email = document.getElementById("regemail").value;              
        var pass = document.getElementById("regpassword").value;            
        var pass2 = document.getElementById("regreenterpassword").value;    
        var tagline = document.getElementById("tagline").value;
        registerOnDB();
    };
    var xmlHttpReg = createXmlHttpRequestObject();               //Calling the function to vaidate input credentials
    function createXmlHttpRequestObject()                        
    {
        var xmlHttpReg;

        if(window.ActiveXObject)                                 //If user is using internet Explorer
        {
            try
            {
                xmlHttpReg = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.xmlHttp");
            }
            catch(e)
            {
                xmlHttpReg=false;
            }
        }
        else                                                     //If user is NOT using internet Explorer but any other browser
        {
            try
            {
                xmlHttpReg = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            catch(e)
            {
                xmlHttpReg=false;
            }
        }

        if(!xmlHttpReg)                                          //If Object can not be initialized.
            {
                alert("Can not create object");
            }
        else
        {
            return xmlHttpReg;
        }
    }
        function registerOnDB()
        {
            if(xmlHttpReg.readyState==0 || xmlHttpReg.readyState==4)                                              //If object state is either 0 OR 4 i.e. object not engaged otherwise.
            {
                var name = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("regname").value);
                var email = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("regemail").value);
                var pass = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("regpassword").value);
                var tagline = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("tagline").value);
                var parameters="name="+name+"&email="+email+"&pass="+pass+"&tagline="+tagline+"&loggedin=true"; 
                var url = "http://localhost/dashboard/x/php/register.php?"+parameters;                            //Sending Data to php script for validation
                xmlHttpReg.open("GET",url,true);                                                                  //Preparing to send request
                xmlHttpReg.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponseReg;                                          //Handling response that will come from php script
                xmlHttpReg.send();                                                                                //sending values to php script

            }
            else
            {
                setTimeout('registerOnDB()', 1000);                                                               //If reasyState is NOT 0 or 4 then repeat then wait and check again after 1 second.
            }
        }


    function handleServerResponseReg()
    {
        if(xmlHttpReg.readyState==4||xmlHttpReg.readyState==0)                                                //If object state is either 0 OR 4 i.e. object not engaged otherwise.
        {
            if(xmlHttpReg.status==200)                                                                        //status 200 means everything went OK
            {
                document.getElementById("errorpromptregister").innerHTML = xmlHttpReg.responseText;           //Putting out message received from XML on the screen at a div whose ID is errorprompt.
            }
            else
            {
                alert("xmlHttp.status!=200");
            }
        }
    }
```

Following is a snippet of my php file-

```
if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO user_tbl(name, tagline, email, password, salt, otp) VALUES ('$name','$tagline','$email','$password','$salt', '$otp')"))
        {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['email']=$email;
            header("Location : otp.php");
            exit();
        }
```

Now the problem is that even though my php script is able to write to Database it is not redirecting to otp.php 
i.e. header function is not working.
Please help me out here on how can i redirect from my php script to otp.php

P.S. - The button is on a bootstrap Modal.

Comment: you're doing an ajax call. That means only the ajax call itself, not the page that the call came from, will be redirected. It's the difference between sending someone to the store to pick something up, and you going to the store to pick up the same thing. If the store's out and tells you to go some other location, both you and the "someone" will get redirected, but YOU won't know the someone was redirected until they come back home and tell you so.

Comment: When you ask a question about an error, **ALWAYS** post the error log. To enable error reporting to your php code, append `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');` at the top of your script, what does it return ?

Answer (score 0):

Redirecting a AJAX request won't change the page that the request was sent from. Redirects happen *before* the page is ever sent to the client, but if the client is sending an AJAX request, obviously they've already been sent the page.

What you could do is return the redirect url back to the client as the AJAX response, then use Javascript to change the page using something like:

```
var ajaxResponse =... 

... 

location.href = ajaxResponse.responseText();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `header()` server-side, use `location.replace` redirect to `otp.php` inside your ajax success callback

Answer (score 0):

As others said you are redirecting the request, not the current page. So on success of the php code, return something like this

```
 echo json_encode( array( 'redirect' => 'http://your location' ));
```

then inside the ajax success grab that `redirect` from data and simply do

```
  $.post('location', {requestdata}, function(data){
     if( data.hasOwnProperty( 'redirect' ) ){
        window.location.href = data.redirect;
    }
 });
```

This way you can tell the calling page where to send the client to.